# How to extract the size of PDF? (Dimensions, not file size)

Tags: pdf, latex, dimensions

I have many hundreds of small PDF images (created in Adobe Illustrator) which will be inserted into a Latex document.  I need to know the size of these images in real-world dimensions (e.g. 20mm x 14mm), or at least something that Latex can understand.

Is there a command line tool that can produce these dimensions?  (I am running Mac OS X.)

A second best solution would some way for Latex to extract the dimensions.

[I have tried pdftk, but its data dump command only seems to tell me the number of pages (1).]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pdfinfo` or `pdfinfo.exe` (from the [**XPDF suite**](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)):

```
pdfinfo ^
   -f 1 ^
   -l 10 ^
   -box ^
   20-pages.pdf
```

This will extract all the page sizes and all the box info (MediaBox, CropBox, BleedBox, TrimBox, ArtBox) for pages 1 - 10 of the PDF.

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Write the following in your LaTeX document:

```
\setbox0 = \hbox{\includegraphics{small.pdf}}
width = \the\wd0, height = \the\ht0
```